# Spring/MyBatis JDBC Connection Refused

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, mybatis, ibatis

Unsure what the issue is here. I have deployed this same WAR file on two different machines, my desktop and a test server, both with the same version of Tomcat (9) and jdk(1.8.0_121). It works on my desktop (Windows 10 x64) but throws this error when on the test server (Ubuntu 16.04).

I have ping'd the database server, so I know it can be reached. I even put a war for a different project on there that accessed the same database and there was no issue connecting.

What could be causing this issue?

```
ERROR - [2017-06-12 10:01:53,898]: c.c.m.c.AuthenticationController:174 login
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is 
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: 
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Network error 
IOException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
### The error may exist in com/company/model/user/User.xml
### The error may involve com.company.model.user.UserMapper.getUserByUsernamePassword
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:79) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:447) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy613.selectOne(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:167) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:75) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:53) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy786.getUserByUsernamePassword(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.company.model.user.DefaultUserService.getUserByUsernamePassword(DefaultUserService.java:33) ~[aps_maven-1.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy789.getUserByUsernamePassword(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.company.mediabuilder.controller.AuthenticationController.login(AuthenticationController.java:129) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.0.M21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
```

Let me know if there are any other configuration files you would like me to include. Since I can't pinpoint the source of the error, I wasn't sure what was relevant.

Regards.

Comment: no takers? unfortunate.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue with several applications recently as well.  A solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my issue, I got it to work by removing all the dependencies in my pom.xml file.  I then built my project each time, looking for errors and subsequently adding each dependency back in.

Turns out I was missing a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```